# redshift or postgresql - create a new column to get users distribution

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have aggregated column one column in the table as following

aggregated table:

```
*-------------------*
| territory | users |
*-------------------*
| worldwide |   20  |
| usa       |   6   |
| germany   |   3   |
| australia |   2   |
| india     |   5   |
| japan     |   4   | 
*-------------------*
```

Below is my desired result in which I want to replicate 'worldwide' data as new column so I can calculate distribution of users.

desired output:

```
*-----------------------------------------------------*
| territory | users | ww_user |  % users distribution |
*-----------------------------------------------------*
| worldwide |   20  |   20    |    0.0                |
| usa       |   6   |   20    |    0.30               |
| germany   |   3   |   20    |    0.15               | 
| australia |   2   |   20    |    0.10               | 
| india     |   5   |   20    |    0.25               | 
| japan     |   4   |   20    |    0.20               | 
*-----------------------------------------------------*
```

I have tried few options in [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Gq2dGTE4) but none of them are getting me desired results.

can anyone give me a direction/idea on how to get my desired results?

Comment: Please add only one tag for the database you are really using. Redshift and Postgres are very different database products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this but it seems like fixing your fiddle would be easiest.  https://dbfiddle.uk/YZLCxDxO

You had a typo (ww vs worldwide) and you need to use the SUM() window function.  Otherwise you were on the right track.

```
with ww_case as (
select territory, users,
  sum(case when territory = 'worldwide' then users else 0 end) over () as ww_users
from my
group by
  1, 2
)
select territory, users, ww_users, users::decimal(5,3) / ww_users as perc
from ww_case
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a CASE WHEN to replace the 1 in worldwide

```
SELECT territory,my.users, my2.users as "users worldwide", ROUND((my.users * 1.0 / my2.users)  ,2)  as "% users distribution"
  FROM my CROSS JOIN (SELECT users FROM my WHERE territory = 'worldwide') my2
```

| territory | users | users worldwide | % users distribution |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| worldwide | 20 | 20 | 1.00 |
| usa | 6 | 20 | 0.30 |
| germany | 3 | 20 | 0.15 |
| australia | 2 | 20 | 0.10 |
| india | 5 | 20 | 0.25 |
| japan | 4 | 20 | 0.20 |

> ```
> SELECT 6
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5NS6mLUL)