# How to populate columns based on different where conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a user table with a last_login column.
I have an additional table called group.
There is also a join table group_user

I have the following query:

```
select count(u.id), group.name
from user u
left join group_user gu where gu.user_id = u.id
left join group g where g.id = gu.group_id  
where u.last_login is not null
group by g.name
```

This generates total users logged in by group.

I then update the query to `where u.last_login is null`

Which generates total users not logged in.

How would I go about pulling all of the data at once with the following columns:

`count(users), count(logged in), count(not logged in), % of total users that have logged in, group name`

Comment: Case expression  `sum(case when u.last_login is null then 1 else 0 end) as NotLoggedIn` `sum(case when u.last_Login is not null then 1 else 0 end) as LoggedIn`  as a cte then do math to get your % is one common design pattern.  There are many others.  you could avoid the case expression and just get a total count by each group subtract to get difference and do math to get % of total as well.  Not sure which would be "faster/better"

Comment: this should give you a hint https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73736643/redshift-or-postgresql-create-a-new-column-to-get-users-distribution/73736798#73736798 besides read up 0on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Are you looking for users who are currently logged in, or users who have logged in since the database started tracking that?  A column named `last_login` gives the impression that if it is null, the user has never logged in.  If it is not null, that doesn't mean they are currently in the system.  Maybe what you really want is `u.last_login > u.last_logout`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT
    g.id AS group_id,
    MAX(g.name) AS group_name,
    COUNT(u.id) AS count_users,
    SUM(u.logged_in) AS count_logged_in,
    COUNT(u.id) - SUM(u.logged_in) AS count_not_logged_in,
    100 * SUM(u.logged_in) / COUNT(u.id) AS percent_logged_in

FROM
    (
    SELECT 
        id, 
        CASE WHEN u.last_login IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS logged_in
    FROM
        user
    ) u
    LEFT JOIN group_user gu ON u.id = gu.user_id
    LEFT JOIN group g ON g.id = gu.group_id
GROUP BY
    g.id -- since two groups could have the same name
;
```